# Laravel same model relationships

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table where I store data IDs from same parent table.

Table 1: id, name ,etc
Table 2: first_id, secound_id

Both first_id and secound_id are linked to tabel 1 > id.

```
public function first() {
$this->belongsTo('First');
}

public function secound() {
$this->belongsTo('First');
}
```

When I do $someobject->first it returns model First. But when i do $someobject->secound it restuns null. Any idea why?

Comment: Given your relation name is exactly the same as the foreign key, ie. `secound` and `secound_id`, you simply don't have related model, that's all. So make sure the key is ok, otherwise provide it as 2nd param to the `belongsTo`